# Excel scatter chart, with grouped text values on the X axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

```
Apples   1
Apples   5
Apples   2
Bananas  1
Bananas  4
Bananas  6
```

I want two bars on the X axis (Apples, Bananas), but with crosses marking the points on the Y axis.

Here's a mockup:

[image]

I'd want 1 and 2 to be labelled "Apples" and "Bananas" respectively.

Comment: isn't there a charts wizard that does this for you?

Comment: I can't find one. Do you know what it's called?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.  Organize your data in a table layout so either Apples and Bananas are column headings and the data is in the columns beneath them, or they are row labels and the data extends to the right on those rows.  Highlight all of the data, including the labels, and insert a Line chart (select the first style that includes markers).  If the X axis doesn't show Apples and Bananas, click the Switch Rows/Columns button.  That will give you a raw graph that looks like this:

[image: Raw Graph]

Then right click on the legend and delete it.  Right click on each series line, select Format Data Series, Line Color, no line.  If the mixed marker styles bothers you, you can click on Marker Options and make them all alike (if the different colors bother you, also click on Marker Fill, solid and pick a color).  You end up with:

[image: polished graph]

This chart style won't give you tick marks at the X axis labels, but those can be added artificially.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think you could rearrange your data into a format like this.

```
apples  bananas
  1        1
  5        4
  2        6
```

Then, each row of the data could be considered as a **single dataset** with the same labels 'apples' and 'bananas'. You could then make the chart you want directly in Excel by trying with inserting a line chart.

But here I can give you another solution which directly draws the dot chart you want. What I did is using the Funfun Excel add-in, this add-in basically enables you to use JavaScript directly in Excel so you are able to use powerful JavaScript libraries like D3.js or Chart.js.

I made a chart with Funfun using Chart.js according to your problem, you could check the chart on the link below

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a281afbcf76561801b7335d

You could also link the URL directly to your Excel. Here is how it looks in Excel.

[image]

[image]

***Disclose: I'm a developer of Funfun***

Comment: Bringing up some ancient posts...

Comment: A publicity stunt?

Comment: Hi Mike, I also modified this answer by adding a [disclose](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) as I answered you in another post you've commented. This is also an ancient post but with even more views (10000+). I just thought my solutions might be useful to others who have similar problems. And I also wrote specific and working JavaScript codes (as people may write VBA code) for this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

To label 1 & 2, you can easily add two dummy series, one for each label.  "Apple" series will be (1,0) and "Banana" series will be (2,0).  Then, format the data points with no shape/fill/line and add a data label for each series name (located below the data point).  Finally, modify the X axis formating to eliminate the default labels (and ticks, if you're inclined).  You may have to tweak the plot area inside the chart to allow for enough room for the data labels.  You'll end up with something like this: [image: Scatter Labels]

You also mentioned two bars on the X axis, with crosses on the Y axis.  Did you mean something like a column chart?  If you elaborate, there's probably an easy way to fix that as well.