# Adding text axis labels to excel scatter chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a Spreadsheet with data like this

```
Label Data
PA_1  1
PA_2  2
PB_1  3
```

with hundreds of rows.

I want to create a scatter graph where the x-axis contains the names in the label column.
Instead, the graph x-axis has numbers instead of the text I want.

This question is similar to [Excel scatter chart, with grouped text values on the X axis](https://superuser.com/questions/400158/excel-scatter-chart-with-grouped-text-values-on-the-x-axis), but the answer that is given would not make sense given the number of data points I have.

To be clear I want to label the axis, not the individual data points.
Is there a way to do this that I am not noticing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is odd....

However, you can mimic the scatter plot by choosing a line chart and then just format the data series line color to be "no line".  You should then get your labels on the horizontal axis.

Comment: Just tested that out and it works. I ended up using a different software package to solve the problem but thank you regardless.